# How to require importlib.resources in a Python setup script

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-importlib

I have a Python package that attempts to import the `importlib.resources` module (added in Python 3.7, as I understand), and then falls back on importing `importlib_resources` if this fails.  `importlib_resources` is provided by the PyPI package `importlib-resources`.

So, I want my pip install dependencies to be "nothing if running 3.7 or newer, importlib-resources otherwise".

Is there some way to specify this dependency in the setup script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional dependencies can be specified using [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers). In a `setup.py` script:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'importlib_resources; python_version < "3.7"',
    ]
)
```

Or, for a declarative build system:

```
# pyproject.toml
[project]
dependencies = [
    'importlib_resources; python_version < "3.7"',
]
```